# Set random text with multidimensional array

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, settext

I'm trying to setText to a textView with multidimensional array with random number. It works fine but only once. How can i make it so that with each button click the text changes itself again and again. Here is my code (I cut it a bit to keep it simple):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
String quiz[][];
int ques;
int ans;
Random myRand = new Random();
int myInt = myRand.nextInt(10);


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        quiz = new String[3][2];

    quiz[0][0] = "Q:1";
    quiz[0][1] = "A:1";

    quiz[1][0] = "Q:2";
    quiz[1][1] = "A:2";

    quiz[2][0] = "Q:3";
    quiz[2][1] = "A:3";



    ques = 0;
    ans = 1;

    button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);

    textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
}
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button4:
                textView2.setText(quiz[myInt][ques]);
                textView3.setText(quiz[myInt][ans]);
            break;
}
}
```

Comment: Generate random number every time when you set a value to a text view. myInt = myRand.nextInt(10); should be inside onClick() method.

Comment: Ah thanks. Made such a stupid mistake sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, you should make new random in `onClick` event

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button4:
                myInt = myRand.nextInt(10);
                textView2.setText(quiz[myInt][ques]);
                textView3.setText(quiz[myInt][ans]);
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You generate a random int only once, when Activity is instantiated. You need to generate it on button click:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button4:
                myInt = myRand.nextInt(10);
                textView2.setText(quiz[myInt][ques]);
                textView3.setText(quiz[myInt][ans]);
            break;
}
```